# why my local object destroyed twice?

Tags: c++, return-value

I have a function returning a local object:

```
class AT
{
public:
    AT() { cout<<"construct"<<endl; }

    AT(const AT& at) { cout<<"copy"<<endl; }

    ~AT() { cout<<"destroy"<<endl; }
};

AT funcAt()
{
    AT tmp;
    return tmp;
}
...
funcAt();
```

output is:

```
construct
copy
destroy
destroy
```

I suppose there are only construct and destroy of "tmp", so why there is copy and another destroy?  where is the copied object?

Comment: No C++ object can be destroyed (or created) twice.

Comment: I'll warrant the output changes if you run a release build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @Neil: I bet I can create and destroy the same object twice. (Author: The pedantic police)

Comment: @Martin Can you step into the same river twice (or even once)? And if so, please post an answer demonstrating it.

Comment: @Neil: Create a normal object. Explicitly call the destructor. Then call placement new to re-initialize the object then normal destructor will then be called when the object goes out of scope. Same object constructed and destroyed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is

1) created: `AT tmp` inside funcAt
2) copied: `return tmp;` and this is because the function returns a copy: `AT funcAt()`
3) destroy - the first tmp object, and the returned copy

Hint: note the `copy` in the output :)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but you need to clean this up to specify TWO objects are being destroyed, not the same one twice.

Answer (score 8):

Let's flesh this out a bit:

```
AT funcAt()
{
    AT tmp;           [1]
    return tmp;       [2]
}                     [3]
...
funcAt();             [4]
```

[1] create an AT object in tmp
[2] copy tmp into return value
[3] destroy tmp
[4] destroy return value because it is not used

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is because the copy of `tmp` is returned from `funcAt` and is not stored anywhere hence C++ destroys it and calls the destructor

Comment: "saved anywhere" is a little confusing to a beginner, I would think. It doesn't really paint the picture of what is happening.

Comment: @San I switched saved to stored. Couldn't think of a better word than that

Answer (score 1):

`tmp` is constructed and destroyed. The same is true for the return value (which is a new object, not just a reference) although here the cop constructor is used. You don't see the return value being used but it's still passed.

Answer (score 0):

The return-value of your function is a separate object (i.e. a copy) to the local object used inside the function.